# AWS Certificate Manager - certificate verify failed via ELB

Tags: ssl, https, aws-acm

I have added Certificate (`.crt`), Key (`.key`) & Certificate Chain ( `star_domain_net.crt` + `DigiCertCA.crt` + `DigiCert Global Root G2.pem` ) to AWS ACM & then attached to ELB.

**DigiCertCA.crt** :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**DigiCert Global Root G2.pem** :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In Private network clients uses following local Certificate File to validate the HTTPS endpoint. This certificate already distributed to All Clients.

**DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt** :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD
QTAeFw0wNjExMTAwMDAwMDBaFw0zMTExMTAwMDAwMDBaMGExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
MRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxGTAXBgNVBAsTEHd3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5j
b20xIDAeBgNVBAMTF0RpZ2lDZXJ0IEdsb2JhbCBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG
9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4jvhEXLeqKTTo1eqUKKPC3eQyaKl7hLOllsB
CSDMAZOnTjC3U/dDxGkAV53ijSLdhwZAAIEJzs4bg7/fzTtxRuLWZscFs3YnFo97
nh6Vfe63SKMI2tavegw5BmV/Sl0fvBf4q77uKNd0f3p4mVmFaG5cIzJLv07A6Fpt
43C/dxC//AH2hdmoRBBYMql1GNXRor5H4idq9Joz+EkIYIvUX7Q6hL+hqkpMfT7P
T19sdl6gSzeRntwi5m3OFBqOasv+zbMUZBfHWymeMr/y7vrTC0LUq7dBMtoM1O/4
gdW7jVg/tRvoSSiicNoxBN33shbyTApOB6jtSj1etX+jkMOvJwIDAQABo2MwYTAO
BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUA95QNVbR
TLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUA95QNVbRTLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUw
DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAMucN6pIExIK+t1EnE9SsPTfrgT1eXkIoyQY/Esr
hMAtudXH/vTBH1jLuG2cenTnmCmrEbXjcKChzUyImZOMkXDiqw8cvpOp/2PV5Adg
06O/nVsJ8dWO41P0jmP6P6fbtGbfYmbW0W5BjfIttep3Sp+dWOIrWcBAI+0tKIJF
PnlUkiaY4IBIqDfv8NZ5YBberOgOzW6sRBc4L0na4UU+Krk2U886UAb3LujEV0ls
YSEY1QSteDwsOoBrp+uvFRTp2InBuThs4pFsiv9kuXclVzDAGySj4dzp30d8tbQk
CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But when client try to authenticate using `ssl` library, it fails with following error.

```
23-09-21 09:43:33 ERROR <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)>: downloading https://util.domain.net/90d11ae0-108e-4103-ae38-8c2fcb617f47.txt
```

I confirmed Server is providing the correct Certificate, by

```
$ openssl s_client -connect util.domain.net:443

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = New York, L = New York, O = My Org Inc, CN = *.domain.net
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = New York, L = New York, O = My Org Inc, CN = *.domain.net
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=My Org Inc/CN=*.domain.net
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Global G2 TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
 1 s:/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=My Org Inc/CN=*.domain.net
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Global G2 TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG4TCCBcmgAwIBAgIQDh4lM1Oqja0xLpEPn2iwkjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBZ
.................
QYlMdVoyhglI+QR9BuwiZbJgOOHC1cf2fdODKocC+zu9IA9N3g==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=My Org Inc/CN=*.domain.net
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Global G2 TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4040 bytes and written 431 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 7579F041C93B46972EA3*0B77F250A3667803010
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 33062D70740974563DB7577*C006D1EEE1AB0B0973FD6FB1595
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1696010288
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---



HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close

closed
```

When I try to add `star_domain_net.crt` + `DigiCertCA.crt` to ACM as certificate Body, I get `certificate body provided is not in a valid PEM format` error in AWS ACM.

I think its the Certificate Chain causing this failure. What I am missing here ?

Comment: Why are you using two different root certificates? You'd need to trust the DigiCert Global Root G2 in the client, not the root you are using now. You actually don't need to configure the root certificate itself at the server; the root certificate is normally not send to the client (as it should already have the root cert as trust anchor).

Comment: *"I confirmed Server is providing the correct Certificate, by ..."* - that actually shows clearly that the server is configured wrong. It provides the server certificate both as leaf and as intermediate and omits the correct intermediate.

Comment: Whats is correct way her ? Use `star_domain_net.crt` + `DigiCertCA.crt` as Certificate Body in AWS ACM / Server ?

Comment: Yes, plus the private key of course. Generally you'd have private key with the leaf and CA cert in that particular order, and the G2 root at the client as trust anchor. Together they make the chain to be verified / validated.

Comment: I have updated OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct order of the certificate chain should be like below,so concatenate the contents of these files in the correct order and then try adding the certificate to AWS ACM again!!!

```
(1) DigiCert Global Root G2.pem 
(2) DigiCertCA.crt
(3) star_domain_net.crt
```